# Docker DNS issue on local machine

Tags: linux, dns, docker

I have an issue with Docker not resolving my local DNS. Running even a basic ping will no longer work. Current version 0.11.1 running on Fedora 20. The last time I worked with docker (version 0.9) everything was fine.

`sudo docker run base ping google.com`
`ping: unknown host google.com`

My local DNS is resolving fine outside of Docker and I don't have localhost (127.0.0.1) set in my resolv.conf file. I have also tried setting the dns with the same outcome:

`sudo docker run --dns=8.8.8.8 base ping google.com`
`ping: unknown host google.com`

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

If anyone else has this issue I got it working by clearing out the iptables:

`iptables -F`

For a more permanent solution after restarting I listed the iptables before and after flushing but couldn't really see what was affecting it. I ended up loading the Firewall Configuration, and enabling the Masquerade zone worked. Not sure why this setting had changed or if a change in newer Docker versions now needed this to be set, but it works. Interestingly I had previously tried just enabling IP forwarding (sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1), but this had no effect for me.